# Create a Footer Block in css

Tags: html, css, footer

I am creating a footer block for my website. I am not an expert with `css`. I am looking to create a block with padding on both left and right side.

Attached is the example of the footer block, I wish to create: [image]

However, the footer block, that I created is spanning over the entire screen. Any idea what could be wrong ?

Here is my css code :

```
#footer-row1{
    margin-top: 80px;
    padding: 1.2em 0;
    background: #000;
    bottom: 0;
    margin-right: -33px;
    font-family: "Fjalla One", Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size: 0.95em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Here is the footer.html code

```
<div id="footer-row1">
                    <div id="footer-bg">
                        <div id="footer" class="container_24">
                            <div class="copyright">
                              #COPYRIGHT#&COPY;{var name='copyright_year'} {var name='sitename'}. &nbsp;&nbsp;{var name='footer_menu'}
                          </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Thanks

Comment: i haven't inderstood very well,but i think you want to replace:    padding: 1.2em 0; with     padding: 0 1.2em;

Comment: Could you supply a fiddle of your existing footer html with this css? Sounds to me your footer isn't contained within a container properly.

Comment: Give it the same `width` as the div above it.

Comment: Thanks @MackieeE, I will check if it is part of container.

Comment: Post your HTML code. Maybe use a fiddle?

Comment: Is that all the CSS? What about the CSS for `#footer-bg` and `#footer` and `.copyright`?

Comment: @MackieeE, Thanks a lot. IT worked. Thanks for your insight and time

Comment: @www.sapnaedu.in No probs =]!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check this **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/aW4yR/1/)**

```
 #footer-row1{
    margin-top: 80px;
    padding: 1.2em 0;
    background: #000;
    bottom: 0;
    margin-right: -33px;
    font-family: "Fjalla One", Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size: 0.95em;
    text-transform: uppercase;

}

.copyright{
    text-align: center;
    color: #FFF;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on my understanding of the above, you can reduce *a lot* and get the footer from the image. All you really need is below:

CSS

```
footer {
    padding: 1.2em 0;
    background: #000;
    font-family: "Fjalla One", Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size: 0.95em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align:center;
    /* you probably need to add some extra styles here */
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="footer">
    #COPYRIGHT#&COPY;{var name='copyright_year'} {var name='sitename'}. &nbsp;&nbsp;{var name='footer_menu'}
</div>
```

This would place something like the image at the bottom of your content.

Comment: I think it is because of the container element. I could fix it. Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: Not sure what frameworks you are using, but there was a lot more HTML than should be necessary. No reason to add more HTML when you don't have to. But happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

The css :

```
#footer-row1{
        margin-top: 80px;
        padding: 1.2em 0;
        background: #000;
        bottom: 0;
        margin-right: -33px;
        font-family: "Fjalla One", Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
        font-size: 0.95em;
        text-transform: uppercase;

    //add
        text-align: center;
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        clear: both; //because you have some float on the previous "row"

    }
```

And add :

```
 #footer-row1 a{ //for you link
        font-family: "Fjalla One", Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
        font-size: 0.95em;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        color: #3399FF; //blue for example
    }

    #footer-previousRow{ //the previous row with list items
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        height: 260px;
    }

    #footer-previousRow ul.listItem{
        list-style: none;
        list-style-type: none;
        min-height: 36px;
        margin: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        display: block;
        float: right;
    }

    ul.listItem li{
       color: #CCCCCC;
    }
```

And your html code for the previousRow :

```
<div class="footer-previousRow">
    <ul class="listItem">
        <li>Contact</li>
        <li>Social</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="footer-row1"> // your actual code
                    <div id="footer-bg">
                        <div id="footer" class="container_24">
                            <div class="copyright">
                              #COPYRIGHT#&COPY;{var name='copyright_year'} {var name='sitename'}. &nbsp;&nbsp;{var name='footer_menu'}
                          </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```